# I want to a Unique query with two columns from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to a Query that shows the meeting date and the active participants name . IN each row show the date meeting and the active participants . they are from different tables  .The table meeting stores only the participants that attend to the meeting .
The first query is like ( table meeting):

```
Select m.date_meet as meeting date from meeting  m where m.date_meet between 
'1-1-2020' and '10-09-2020'
```

and the other select is (table participants) :

```
select p.participants_name as participant name from participants p where p.start <
'some_unique_Date' and p.end > 'some_unique_date'
```

Another example :

imagine the result of this query  is 4 rows
`select m.date_meet as meeting date from meeting  m where m.date_meet between '1-1-2020' and '10-09-2020'`
like :

meeting date

1. 1-20-2020
2. 4-10-2020
3. 7-20-2020
4. 9-25-2020

So for each row pass it for the second query :

```
select p.participants_name from participants p where p.start <
```

'some_unique_Date' and p.end > 'some_unique_date'

that means:

```
    select p.participants_name as participant name from participants p
 where p.start < '1-20-2020' and p.end > '1-20-2020'
    select p.participants_name as participants name from participants p 
where p.start < '4-10-2020' and p.end > '4-10-2020'
    select p.participants_name as participants name from participants p
 where p.start < '7-20-2020' and p.end > '7-20-2020'
    etc .. .
```

And the result that I want is something like :

```
meeting date | Active Participants name 

 1. 1-20-2020   | john , Eduards, mike, Daniel, Maria
 2. 4-10-2020   | Eduards, mike, Daniel,Maria Ali
 3. 7-20-2020   | john , Eduards, mike, Maria, Ali, Joe, Carls
 4. 9-25-2020   | Mike, Maria, Louise, Anna, Cristopher, Elton
```

the table participants have fields like star,end and name. that mean the beginning of the activation of the participant, the end of participant' activation period  and the name.
The table meeting have fields like date_meeting , number_meeting, participants_meeting .

Comment: Please provide the CREATE TABLE statements for the 2 tables and some sample data for them. Is there some relationship between a meeting and its participants (other than just dates)? Does a meeting just last for a single day? Can no 2 meetings overlap dates?

Comment: I just resolve this query I show you an example.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve it by doing a single query . in the select field I did another query.

```
    select   number_meet , date_meet , 
 meet_particip ,
array((select  unnest(string_to_array(string_agg(LOWER(dir.dir_diretor),','),',')) FROM srd_diretoria dir WHERE 
        dir.dir_start <   date_meet  ANd (dir.dir_end is null OR 
dir.dir_end  > red_date_meet) aND dir.dir_diretor is not null ) except select unnest
(( array_remove(regexp_split_to_array( srd_diretores_particip, '#'), '') )) )
        as " Ausentes "  from  meeting  
where date_meet > '1-1-2020' and date_meet < '31-12-2020' 
order by number_meet , date_meet
```

In this query I put all rows from dir_diretor in one row , by using the function unnest() combining with the function string_to_array() . I used the except to compare two subqueries: One query is the active participants another is the presents to the meeting. this except subtracts this two subqueries.